# How to initialise vector member variable in constructor of class template

Tags: c++, templates, vector, constructor, stl

I'm trying to initialise a vector member variable in the constructor of a class template.  I'm getting "'T' does not refer to a value" error from the compiler, because T refers to a class, so I can't do what I want with this format.  What's the correct format here for the constructor please? (I'm guessing I need to convert T to be const val_type, as per the [constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/)?)

```
template <class T>
    class PeripheralSystem {
        public:
            PeripheralSystem(uint32_t numPeripherals = 0) : peripherals(numPeripherals, T) {};
            virtual ~PeripheralSystem();

        private:
            std::vector<T> peripherals;

    };
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ? Default construct numPeripherals objects ?

Comment: Just removing the `, T` from your constructor will fix it, if I'm correctly guessing what you're trying to do.

Comment: @DrewDormann would not work for c++11

Comment: Yes, thanks, construct a vector containing numPeripherals number of objects of class T.

Comment: @Slava are you sure?  I can't guess why C++11 would reject that, or find a C++11 compiler that rejects that.

Comment: @DrewDormann look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector and notice constructor difference since c++11 and until.

Comment: @Slava So? There's still a constructor that only takes a size.

Comment: @Slava I was just looking there.  Constructor `vector( size_type count );` seems to remain valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the intent is for the `vector` to have an initial size of `numPeripherals` elements, then use

```
PeripheralSystem(uint32_t numPeripherals = 0) : peripherals(numPeripherals) {};
```

Now `peripherals` will have `numPeripherals` value-initialized (which is default initialization if `T` is a class type) instances of `T`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to initialize all elements with default value just use this form:

```
PeripheralSystem(uint32_t numPeripherals = 0) : peripherals(numPeripherals, T() ) {};
```

you can just omit that parameter, `std::vector` constructor had T() as default value for that argument until c++11 or has a constructor accepting only size since:

```
// until c++11
explicit vector( size_type count, 
                 const T& value = T(),
                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
// since c++11
vector( size_type count, 
             const T& value,
             const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
explicit vector( size_type count );
```

as stated at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to initialise the `vector<T>` with objects of type `T`, so use something like:

```
PeripheralSystem(uint32_t numPeripherals = 0) : peripherals(numPeripherals, T()) {};
```